# Rails - Dynamic form with radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Basically I'm trying to list all events from my database on a website using this code:

```
<table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Event</th>
                <th>Join Event?</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>        
           <% @events.each do |e| %>    
           <p>              
            <tr>            
              <td>
              <div>
                <%= e.name %>
              </div>
              </td>
              <td>
              <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">                                       
                 <button class="btn" class-toggle="btn-success"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>
                 <button class="btn btn-danger active" class-toggle="btn-danger"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>                                               
              </div>    
              </td>
            </tr>           
           </tbody>                 
            <% end %>              
           </table>
```

You can easily join an event by clicking on a radio button. Now my problem is how can I save this form in Rails? In this example I have joined(=clicked) Event 2. What is the best way to save this form back into the database. Ideally I have a "Update" or "Save" button at the end of the website, which does that for me.

But when I add a simple submit button like this to the my form

```
...same code as above
          </td>
        </tr>           
       </tbody>  
            <%= f.submit 'Save form' %>        
        <% end %>              
       </table>
```

then my submit button will be triggered everytime I click on one of my radio buttons. Does anyone know a fix to this problem?

Comment: Sorry, why would adding a submit button cause radio buttons to submit the form? Adding a button shouldnt change the behavior of any other part of the form...

Answer (score 0):

well, it is fairly simple to do a event[] radio button that when submitted will submit an array of the selected options.

The button tags would look like this, adjusting for your classes etc.

```
<%= radio_button_tag event[], e.id %>
```

then the controller would look like

```
def create
  ...
  user.events = params[:event] unless params[:event].empty?
  user.save
  ...
end
```

This ofcoarse assumes that you have a column in your user model to store events they are going to. A more flexible model would be to have user :has_many events :through => user_events. The same controller logic would apply, except it would look like

```
def create
  ...
  if params[:event]
    params[:event].each do |e|
      user.user_event.new(:event_id => e)
    end
  end
  ....
end
```

Resources:
Form tag helpers: [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag)
Using :has_many :through associations : [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) (section 2.4)